# Under which condition arbitrary Union of ideals is an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

I was wondering some condition for it as Union of two ideals is ideal if either of them is contained in other! Someone may help.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You may also find the answer given to this question interesting (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524077/union-and-sum-of-ideals-is-not-ideal)

Comment: If either of them is contained in the other means the ideals are  equal. This is not  the exact condition.

Comment: See [Direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Okay sure thanks:)

Comment: Alekos Robotis 's answer is perfect. It is in the book "Multiplicative Ideal Theory" by Gilmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a collection $\Sigma=\{\mathfrak{a}_i\}_{i\in I}$ of ideals in a unital ring $A$, then $\bigcup_{i\in I} \mathfrak{a}_i$ is still an ideal if $\Sigma$ is a directed set under $\subseteq$. That is, if for any pair of indices $i,j$, there exists an index $k$ so that $\mathfrak{a}_i\subseteq \mathfrak{a}_k$ and $\mathfrak{a}_j\subseteq \mathfrak{a}_k$.

In particular, a nested union of ideals is an ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{C}:=\{I_k : k \in K\}$ be a set of ideals in a ring $R$. Put $I:= \bigcup_{k \in K} I_k$. The question is: "When is $I$ an ideal of $R$?"

Here is a sufficient condition, which is a good exercise:

$\mathcal{C}$ is a chain, that is for all $k,l \in K$ we have either $I_k \subseteq I_l$ and $I_l \subseteq I_k$.