# If $I,J,K$ are ideals of a ring $R$ with identity and $I,J \subseteq K$, show that $K$ contains the ideal $I+J$.

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I don't know how to go about starting this question.

I've written down the definitions of what it means for $I,J$ and $K$ to be ideals of $R$, but don't know where to go from there.

i.e.

$(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$ and $I$ is closed under multiplication by any element $r \in R.$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1524077/union-and-sum-of-ideals-is-not-ideal) might be of use to you here.

Comment: Which *definition* of ideal sum are you using? One definition  is ideal $K \supset I+J\iff K\supset I,J,\,$ i.e. $I+J$ is the smallest ideal containing both $I,J.\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

The elements of both Ideals $I$ and $J$ are in $K$: Let $i \in I, j \in J$, it holds true that $i,j \in K$. $K$ has a group structure, so the sum of two of it's elements are in $K$ and therefore $i+j \in K$.

Now, let $\lambda \in R$. Since $K$ in an ideal, you stay in $K$ if you multiply any element of $K$ by $\lambda$ and we can apply this to $i+j$, since $i+j \in K \implies \lambda(i+j) \in K$.

And elements of the form $\lambda(i+j) \in K$, are exactly those of the Ideal $I+J$ (recall the definition). So we have just shown that any element of $I+J$ is indeed in $K$, thus $I+J \subset K$.